# Ionic - Can't center align ion-search bar in header

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm having a lot of trouble centering a ion-searchbar in my navigation bar. 
I've tried text-align and ion-grids, but nothing seems to work. I has to be the component.

[image: Ionic 2/3 Mobile]

index.html

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <button class="home-menu" ion-button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
        <h1>Title Here</h1>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-searchbar class="search" [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)">
    </ion-searchbar>
</ion-navbar>
```

index.scss

```
page-index {
    ion-searchbar {
        width: 60 % ;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
page-index {
    ion-searchbar {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: No way! All I needed was 'auto'.. Thank you very much itodd! Saved me from more headaches :^)